# Count Length and then Count those records.

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a view that displays size (char) of LastName and the total number of records whose last name has that size. So far I have:

```
SELECT LENGTH(LastName) AS Name_Size
FROM Table
ORDER BY Name_Size;
```

I need to add something like

```
COUNT(LENGTH(LastName)) AS Students
```

This is giving me an error. Do I need to add a GROUP BY command? I need the view:

```
Name_Size       Students
       3            11
       4            24
       5            42
```

Comment: Please include the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LENGTH(LastName) as Name_Size, COUNT(*) as Students
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name_Size
ORDER BY Name_Size;
```

You may have to change the group by and order by to LENGTH(LastName) as not all SQL engines let you reference an alias from the select statement in a clause on that same statement.

HTH,
Eric

Comment: If you GROUP BY you don't need to ORDER BY. GROUP BY does sorting to apply the grouping

Comment: This is not true in Oracle... it might be sorted in order depending on the query plan but the only way for the order to be 100% right all of the time is to also use order by.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:74320098178823

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change the GROUP BY just like you said. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Cratylus:  In this simple example it won't matter, but that's not always the case.  What if instead of Name_Size in Asc, the output needed to be sorted by Student Count Desc??  Then you'd HAVE to use the ORDER BY clause

Comment: It matters because it makes the query unnecessarily longer. The GROUP BY in most DBMS is implemented via sorting. Of course if you need to reverse sort then you would need to explicitly do that, but this is not the case

Comment: The extra size of the query is trivial. And as previously stated Oracle doesn't guarantee the order unless you use order by. Same for SQL Server by the way. It all depends on what the CBO decides to do for the execution. A lot of times it will match but not always.